# Compare Datetime Columns in Dataframe with Criteria

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe with two datetime columns is it possible to retun only rows where ATime is no more than 1 minute before BTime? Note it should also return rows where ATime is greater than BTime.

Original:

| Atime | BTime |
| --- | --- |
| 06/01/2017 19:58:01 | 06/01/2017 20:00:00 |
| 06/01/2017 19:59:01 | 06/01/2017 20:00:00 |
| 06/01/2017 20:00:01 | 06/01/2017 20:00:00 |

Result:

| Atime | BTime |
| --- | --- |
| 06/01/2017 19:59:01 | 06/01/2017 20:00:00 |
| 06/01/2017 20:00:01 | 06/01/2017 20:00:00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert columns to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and compare difference of columns ig less like `1 Minute`, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Atime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Atime'], dayfirst=True)
df['BTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BTime'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df[df['BTime'].sub(df['Atime']).lt(pd.Timedelta('1 Min'))]
print (df1)
                Atime               BTime
1 2017-01-06 19:59:01 2017-01-06 20:00:00
2 2017-01-06 20:00:01 2017-01-06 20:00:00
```